# Markov chain or not? (sum of dice rolls) mod #

Tags: probability, markov-chains

you are rolling a dice and each data point is the sum of all rolls up to that point mod 8.  is this a markov chain?

its supposed to be, but i cant see it.

if the first roll is 1 and second roll is 5, then the third roll can give the sum 7,8,...,12.  taking mod 8 you have {7,0,1,2,3,4}
if first roll is 2 and second roll is 5, then the sum of first three rolls can be 8,9,...13.  taking mod 8 you have {0,1,2,3,4,5}

these two sets are different, how is this a markov chain?
basically I cant figure out how to write a transition matrix for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Markov property basically says that the single-step transition probabilities don’t depend on the history of the process: The only thing that matters for these probabilities is the current state, not how you got there. So, for instance, if after the first two rolls the total is 6, it doesn’t matter whether the first two rolls were 1&5, 2&4, or any other sequence of die rolls. The probability of the total’s being 7 after the next roll is $\frac16$, regardless.